# Angular 10 library without ivy

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I built an Angular 10 library and used it via a direct import (`file:dist/my-lib`).

Now I wanted to publish my lib to a private npm repository.
To get that working, I changed my `tsconfig.lib.json` and disabled ivy:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

All that worked, and I was able to build and publish my library.
Most of the library code is working as expected, but in one component (internally used inside the library) there is a function:

```
export class MyComponent {
  public hasChanges(): boolean {
    return ...;
  }
}
```

I do invoke this function on an injected `@ViewChild('myCustomComponent') myComponent: MyComponent;`, which throws an error that hasChanges is not a function.

I do not really know what one would need to figure out the problem.
Any thoughts what could be the problem with disabling ivy?

Everything works fine when I build the library without disabling ivy.

Comment: Im not sure if Ivy is the problem here, but the declaration should really be `@ViewChild('myCustomComponent') myComponent: MyComponent | undefined;` ViewChilds are only defined after `ngAfterViewInit`, calling them prior to that can potentially be dangerous.

Comment: I just tried to remove the call to the `hasChanges` function and found out that `MyComponent` is completely omited. It does not even include any HTML from that component in the DOM.

I think it has at least something to do with ivy, because when I remove `enableIvy: false` from `tsconfig.lib.json`, everything works

Comment: you need to declare it, and maybe even add it as entryComponent, depending on the usage, if you disable ivy.

Comment: Adding it to entry components is something that I partly understand.

But I only build my lib without ivy, since it is not allowed to push ivy-built libraries to a registry.
But in the project where I use the library, ivy is enabled. Shouldn't it work with this setting?

Comment: Does adding {static: true} to your ViewChild definition help: @ViewChild('myCustomComponent', {static:true}) myComponent: MyComponent

Comment: Already tried that. Did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using Angular >= 11 and the partial compilation mode.

In `tsconfig.lib.json`:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "compilationMode": "partial"
}
```

[See here for further explanation](https://blog.lacolaco.net/2021/02/angular-ivy-library-compilation-design-in-depth-en/#how-to-compile-libraries-with-ivy)

Comment: It would be nice to correct the link, it takes you to some Japanese blog.